# How do I interact with an Old Tree that is near Otrodnoe?

Tags: atom-rpg

South of Otrodnoe on your way to the Bandit Factory there is a fuel Truck.
[image]
Inside the encounter next to the truck there is a tree, when clicking on it your char says:

"I get weird vibes from this place" or "It feels as if someone is watching me".

[image]

I am assuming I need some specific item in my hand... I have already tried eating mushrooms and getting drunk in the area but nothing is happening...

**How do I progress story here, how do I interact with the tree?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tree is part of a quest chain later which involves interaction with it, there is nothing for you to do at this time.

Here is the details of the quest involved:

> Later on in the game, when you meet the smugglers in the sewers under Krasnoznamenny, one of the jobs will involve making a pickup of a drug drop at that tree.